# How to measure the elapsed time since last call of a function?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a decorator in order to measure the time that has been passed since the last call of the function that I am decorating. This is my solution so far:

```
def timingRequests(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Elapsed time since last request: {}".format(time.time() - timeLastRequest))
        timeLastRequest = time.time()
        print("Current request time: {:.2f}".format(timeLastRequest))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I think that it is a good solution. My problem is the variable `timeLastRequest`. It is a global variable, but I don't know how to properly update it, since the `timeLastRequest` inside wrapper function is local. Adding the keyword global to this variable does not help.

Comment: why don't you define `timeLastRequest` within `timingRequest`? Another option is to make a class decorator and use a class property to store

Comment: Don't edit a solution in to the question. This breaks the Q&A model of the site. It is perfectly fine to post answers to your own question, and even accept them!